# Is there a comment convention for matlab?

Tags: matlab, comments

I try to search Google to get a comment convention for Matlab code.
I found some guidelines like "you should write comments clearly and easily to read".
However, there is no such document which explains how many spaces, how many %, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "MATLAB Programming Style Guidelines" has a section about comments: http://www.datatool.com/downloads/matlab_style_guidelines.pdf I think it is the best you can find.

Comment: Thank you @Andrey. In this guideline, I found just a few comment's convention. Are there another guideline?